# Why can integrals of non-continuous functions be defined?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, 
$$\int^a_b\frac{1}{x}=\int^b_0\frac{1}{x}-\int^a_0\frac{1}{x}$$
The LHS of this expression is defined for any $a,b$ given $|b|>|a|$ and $a,b\neq0$, but I don't see why this is the case when considering the RHS. Is it trivial to say that the $\ln0$ from each of the indefinite integrals cancel out? $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate (though since both are from $\ln0$ I could see this making sense).

The video that got me thinking about this is found here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQRttF8-iqA, subtracting $\sum\frac{1}{x}$ from both sides of the equation leads to a contradiction because it diverges. Similarly, the limit as x approaches 0 of $\ln{x}$ does not exist. Writing $\ln{x}$ as a taylor series can create a similar situation e.g
$$I=\int^b_0\frac{1}{x}-\int^a_0\frac{1}{x}$$
$$I= \ln b -\ln 0 - \ln a + \ln 0$$
$$I + \sum_{n=1}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n}}= \ln b - \ln a + \sum_{n=1}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n}}$$
(Perhaps assuming I can add ln0 on both sides also implies that ln0-ln0 = 0?)

How can $I$ in this example be defined when it can be rearranged into this non-trivial situation, when the linked video lead to a contradiction. More generally for any definite integral that passes over a point of divergence, can it be assumed always that $\infty - \infty = 0$? Are there opposite cases where the definite integral is not defined for a function anywhere because of this?

Please keep answers to basic analysis level, I have found a few questions that (I think) are similar to my own, but the answers seem very daunting, however it feels like there should be a simple answer.

Comment: I think this would make more sense in the form of an improper integral $\lim_{c\to 0} \int_c^b \frac{dx}{x} - \int_c^a \frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: $\int_a^b1/x\,dx$ is not defined for $a < 0 < b$, neither as a Riemann integral nor a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: as you defined $\int_a^b \frac1x dx$ as "cancelling" the "logarithm of zero" it seems similar to the concept of [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: The integral $I$ is not well defined, as obviously $\operatorname{ln}(0)$ isn't. Whay you do here is similar to calculating the cauchy principle value, which is what you should search for to find out more about such situations.  The problem wich your solution using infinte series is that you do not regard convergence issues of those, i.e. the difference of two diverging series, if you take it componentwise, can be a converging series, but that doesn't mean that you can somehow "add" the (non-existent) limits, as you do here